# Laravel scheduled command via CRON not running

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, cron, laravel-5.1

I have a Laravel 5.1 site, and an artisan command set up that I can run manually without problems, but I cannot seem to get it to fire at a scheduled time.

I have a crontab set up on a digital ocean server, the contents of the file are

```
HELL=/bin/bash
MAILTO=""

* * * * * php /var/www/{domain}/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

where {domain} is the actual domain.

In my kernel.php file I have the following

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('migrate:existing-users')->dailyAt('10:25');
}
```

There's nothing in the laravel log file that offers any clues, it just seems like nothing it happening.

How can I check if the cron is set up correctly?

**EDIT:**

It seems the cron tab was set up under the root user, so I have also set up another one under www-data, and put this simple line in both

```
* * * * * echo 'run this command every minute'
```

with my email address in the `MAILTO=` line, but nothing gets emailed to me on either crontab

Comment: Which user is the owner / group for `/var/www/{domain}/artisan`? If it's, say, `apache2` or `www-user`, then check that you've added the crontab entry to the correct users's crontab:  `sudo -p apache2 crontab` . it's possible that you have added the job to the wrong user's crontab and thats why it doesn't seem to run.

Comment: Thanks for that @Anthony I think my crontab was set for root user, and I think the default user is www-data so set a crontab for that user and basically copied everything from one file to the other but it still isn't running!